# Request Entity Too Large for Self Hosted ASP.Net Web API

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, xmlhttprequest

I have a **large chunk of json** that I need to post to a **self hosted ASP.Net Web API** Service.

I get the "**Status Code:413 Request Entity Too Large**" message.

Tried to put the following in the app.config of the webapi service project.

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <httpRuntime
        maxRequestLength="2147483647"
        executionTimeout="300" />
</system.web>
```

**This didn't help.**

I am thinking about the following two options.

1. Decompress the data in javascript possibly using [LZW compression library](http://blog.istepaniuk.com/client-side-compression-with-javascript/) and decode it on the webapi side after receiving.
2. Find a way to allow the webapi infrastructure to allow large chunk of data

**I prefer the 2nd option**, but have not yet found how to make it happen.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I was getting the same problem and was able to make the change in code.

```
var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration(host);
config.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647; // use config for this value
/*
other setup for the config
*/
using (var server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config))
{
    server.OpenAsync().Wait();
    Console.WriteLine("Insight.Web");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: That is the correct answer. I accidentally figured it out as I was going through the properties on config, before you replied, and worked like a charm.